# WPF - Infinite datagrid height

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Syncfusion's SfDataGrid instead of standard one, but this question is more about XAML, not the control itself, I think.

So, I have a window with DataGrid. If there is for example 60 records, then the window gets really tall. I want the window not to change its size at all. And really don't know why it's happening.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding Info}">
            <TextBlock Text="Amount:"/>
            <sf:CurrencyTextBox Value="{Binding Amount}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
            <!-- some other controls -->

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LeftLabel}"
                           Text="Count:"/>
                <sf:UpDown Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,5"
                           Value="{Binding Count}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LeftLabel}"
                           Text="Year count:"/>
                <sf:UpDown Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                           Value="{Binding YearCount}"/>
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,10,5" 
                Content="Simulate >>"
                Command="{Binding SimulateCommand}"/>
    </Grid>

<!-- This is right part of the window with datagrid -->
    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="Total amount:" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalAmount"/>
        </WrapPanel>

<!-- and the datagrid -->
        <sf:SfDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       AllowDeleting="False"
                       AllowEditing="False"
                       IsReadOnly="False"
                       AllowGrouping="False"
                       AllowFiltering="False"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding History}">
            <sf:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                <sf:GridDateTimeColumn DisplayBinding="{Binding Date}" MappingName="PaymentDay" HeaderText="Date"/>
                <sf:GridCurrencyColumn DisplayBinding="{Binding Amount}" MappingName="PayAmount" HeaderText="Amount"/>
            </sf:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        </sf:SfDataGrid>

    </DockPanel>        
</Grid>
```

So what is wrong with it?

Comment: Try replacing your DockPanel with a Grid, where the RowDefinition containing the `DataGird` has '*' as Height

Comment: I tried, in fact Grid was at the beginning. Then I read somewhere to change it to dockpanel.

Comment: Try to set Window height to Auto' or '*'.

Comment: What's the `Height` of the window? Did you set the `SizeToContent` property?

Comment: MinHeight is set to 400. Actually it's UserControl, so it does not have SizeToContent. But the window that is parent of this control have SizeToContent set to "WidthAndHeight" and it should not be changed. As this is ma "base dialog window".